# Add Tab Bar and Navigation Bar to App

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I'm new to iOS development.  I'm attaching a link to my project so that hopefully someone can help me with this.  I need to add a tab bar with four items (home, about us, contact us, and a link to a website that will open in safari).  The same three items will be on every view except for a couple exceptions.  The "home" screen will not need the home item, the about us page won't need that item, and contact us won't need that item.

I'm also wanting a navigation bar that will have a back button on each view and display the title of that page.

Here is the link to my project:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/sv0y3oh1aftxl95/KFBNewsroom%204.zip

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you in solving problem

```
// set up a local nav controller which we will reuse for each view controller
UINavigationController *localNavigationController;

// create tab bar controller and array to hold the view controllers
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

NSMutableArray *localControllersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];

// setup the first view controller (Root view controller)
RootViewController *myViewController;
myViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithTabBar];

// create the nav controller and add the root view controller as its first view
localNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
localNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
localNavigationController.delegate = self;

[localControllersArray addObject:localNavigationController];

// release since we are done with this for now
[localNavigationController release];
[myViewController release];

tabBarController.viewControllers = localControllersArray;
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;  

tabBarController.delegate = self;
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.delegate = self;

// release the array because the tab bar controller now has it
[localControllersArray release];

self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;

// add the tabBarController as a subview in the window
self.window.rootiviewcontroller = self.tabbarcontroller;
```

// need this last line to display the window (and tab bar controller)
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: I'm guessing all of this gets added to KFBAppDelegate.m?

Comment: I haven't added it yet.  I was just verifying where it needs to go before I do anything with it.

Comment: I was asking where in my project the code should go.  I guessing in the AppDelegate.m file?

Comment: initially your app needs tabbar as initial means then it should be placed in AppDelegate.m file

Comment: Care to elaborate?  Like I said in my post, I'm new to iOS.

Comment: please use this url http://prassan-warrior.blogspot.in/2011/09/programmatically-create-tabbar.html

Answer (score 0):

instead of pushing view controllers directly onto the tabbar, first create a navigation controller and initialize it with a rootviewcontroller of its specific controller

```
Settings *settingsVC = [[Settings alloc] init];
UINavigationController *settingsNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsVC];
Report *reportVC = [[Report alloc] init];
UINavigationController *reportNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:reportVC];
Episodes *episodesVC = [[Episodes alloc] init ];
UINavigationController *episodesNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:episodesVC];
UINavigationController *homeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeVC];

NSArray* controllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:settingsNavigationController,
                               reportNavigationController,
                               episodesNavigationController,
                               homeNavigationController, nil];
```